# Why was Chewing Gum cancelled?

Tags: cancellation, chewing-gum

I honestly really liked the first 2 seasons. I was excited for the third season only to realize it's not coming out.

Why was the third season of [Chewing Gum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chewing_Gum_(TV_series)) (on Netflix in the US) cancelled?

Comment: FYI this is not a Netflix show, it's just distributed by Netflix in the USA

Answer (score 10):

Seems like the show's creator, Michaela Coel, simply doesn't want to do the show anymore. According to several articles, she originally had put it on hold to focus on other projects, but now she's said she is done with it.

Here are some quotes from an [interview](https://themuse.jezebel.com/michaela-coel-wont-write-a-third-season-of-chewing-gum-1832263770).

> **Q: Would you do a third season of Chewing Gum?**
>
> No. It’s so strange, I kind of relish in this news. It’s like I love giving this bad news. I love telling people it’s over. The party is over. I don’t know why I love it so much because it’s not real, but look you’re still alive, right? It’s like, I get messages from people, they say the wanna kill themselves. “I’m gonna kill myself if you don’t do another season.” You’re still here though, right? Look at that.﻿
>
> **Q: Would you do it for Netflix?**
>
> No. Listen, I had a message from someone saying, “I hope you don’t mind, I’ve done a season three.” I’m like, “Good. Do it.” I’m not doing another season. Anybody else can do it. Please, anybody. I’m just not doing it. That’s all. Everybody has permission. I’m just not. For real. [Giggles.]

Comment: That seems weird. She doesn't really give a reason besides "I like telling people bad news".

Answer (score -1):

It was cancelled because Michaela was sexually assaulted while writing season 2. The response from the producers was mixed and one of the producers said he wanted “to f*** her.” She did an interview about it in 2018:

[Michaela Coel says she was sexually assaulted while writing Chewing Gum](https://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/tv/news/michaela-coel-sexual-assault-chewing-gum-channel-4-black-mirror-a8504396.html?amp)

Comment: The article doesn't say that's the reason the show ended.

Comment: Also not one of the producers [of the show], but "an unnamed television executive", later referred to as "this producer".